# electron + react router: initial app is not at root route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron

I have a setup in electron with react router. When I load the app into my browser, and don't go via electron, everything works fine, and the router is good.

When I use it in electron however, my software is not at the root route initially. I can navigate to the root route with the links I created, and that works fine. But it's not there initially, I get a 404. But I don't get any errors as such.

So when i start it, it looks like this:

[image]

But the Links all work, so I can click for example on Home at am redirected to the Home route:

[image]

My switch looks like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
  <Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

And that component sits in another component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header.jsx'
import Main from './Main.jsx'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <Header />
        <Main />
      </div>);
  }
}
```

which sits in this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

and here is also the Main.js which holds the Routes:

```
 const Main = () => (
   <main>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
       <Route component={NotFound}/>
     </Switch>
   </main>
 )
```

So as far as I am concerned, everything should be working fine, and, as I said, it does in the browser. But electron does not seem to start my react router at `/`. Why could this be?

Comment: Did you manage to handle the default page in your app?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Oh.. okay :/.. I got it working without the exact prop in the Route component but I'm pretty sure that may provoke some issues later